# How do I reference a local hdfs file from within mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'd like to reference a file that is on the hdfs cluster in hadoop from within my mapreduce script.

Is it possible to do this without using the full path (hdfs://ip/path/to/file) but instead using a local /path/to/file reference?  I'm using java and tried something like:

```
    File file = new File(stringPathToFile);
```

But that seems to reference the local filesystem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: but HDFS access will be faster than local file access , So better you give the HDFS path..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to access the file with the [Hadoop API](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Hdfs.html). You are probably looking for [open](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Hdfs.html#open%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20int%29). This will give you a stream that acts like a generic open file. `File` doesn't know how to deal with files in HDFS.

I found this [code example](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs) that shows how to do this.

---

**Edit:** After reading your question again, I noticed you are accessing this from inside of a MapReduce job. If the file is small enough (can sit on the disk of one computer), you should strongly consider using [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html). This pushes the file to every node running the job so that it can be accessed quickly. Reading off of HDFS with several mappers can induce a networking bandwidth bottleneck in your job.